# Пагинация не работает на сервере, хотя работает на локальном сервере

Tags: php, yii, веб-сервер

Проблема заключается в том, что пагинация стабильно работает на локальном сервере, но сервере реальном, происходят ошибки. Он не загружает все товары по категориям, только часть загружает. И порой если нет страницы он пишет что она есть но результат поиска пустой

Вот код:

```
public function getListForCategory(StoreCategory $category, $withChild = true, $limit = null)
    {
        $categories = [];

        if (true === $withChild) {
            $categories = $category->getChildsArray();
        }

        $categories[] = $category->id;

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria([
            'scopes' => ['published'],
        ]);

        $builder = new CDbCommandBuilder(Yii::app()->getDb()->getSchema());

        $criteria->addInCondition('t.category_id', array_unique($categories));
        $criteria->addCondition(sprintf('t.id IN (SELECT product_id FROM {{store_product_category}} WHERE %s)',
            $builder->createInCondition('{{store_product_category}}', 'category_id', $categories)), 'OR');

        $pagination = [
            'pageSize' => (int)Yii::app()->getModule('store')->itemsPerPage,
            'pageVar' => 'page',
        ];

        if ($limit) {
            $pagination = false;
            $criteria->limit = (int)$limit;
        }

        return new CActiveDataProvider(
            Product::model(),
            [
                'criteria' => $criteria,
                'pagination' => $pagination,
                'sort' => [
                    'sortVar' => 'sort',
                    'defaultOrder' => 't.position',
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
```

[image: Один из примеров ошибки]